# is it possible to emulate my click actions on IE11 to automatize the actions of "SAVE a bunch of SVG images AS PNG in a folder"?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, emulation

For all my SVGs in my folder, their viewport starts from x=0px & y=0px.

Is set of below actions possible/achievable with a standalone script in jQuery library?

```
foreach SVG file in folder
    open current SVG file in IE11 in new tab
    move cursor to x=10px y=10px
    right click
    select "save image as" from new GUI
    select "PNG (*.png)"
    click save
    if exists
        open next SVG file in IE11 in new tab
        close previous IE11 tab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any Jquery library that lets you automate the IE browser. Instead of that, I suggest you refer to the [Selenium IE web driver](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). This is a more suitable option to automate the IE browser. Also, it is available in many developing languages. so you can use whichever you are familiar with.

If we try to check your automation requirement then we can see that you want to save the image stored in the folder by automating the IE browser.

I don't think any library or automation solution will allow you to directly access the folder where images are stored.

If we talk about the image download part then it is not possible to automate the Save file dialogue using Selenium. Because the Save file dialogue is a part of a Windows OS.

To automate this step, you may need to use any GUI automating library along with the Selenium web driver.

So I suggest you rethink the automation approach and make necessary changes in the logic to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your valuable information. My environment is very strict. I shall not use 3rd party softwares. I will rethink on my logic/pseudocode to fulfil my automatization purpose. Thanks again, regards.

Comment: If it answers your question then you can consider to accept it as an answer.